# Problem with while/foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, dataset

I need to solve the following problem but I still dont know how.

```
First DataTable:
Name: WingsBookingInterface
Sample Data:
WingsBookingInterfaceId    Columnx ColumnY WingsDossierID
1                          x       y       1
2                          x       y       1
3                          x       y       1
4                          x       y       2

Table: WingsBookingDetail
WingsBookingDetailId         WingsBookingInterfaceId  Columnx  Columny
1                            1                        x        y
2                            1                        x        y
3                            1                        x        y
4                            2                        x        y
5                            2                        x        y
```

I need to iterate through all the rows from the detail table that have the same DossierID in the master table.

Then I need to commit some operation with that group.

Then I need to continue the loop

I dont know how to do this,  the only thing I have is the external loop

```
foreach (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row in _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Rows)
{
    dossierId = row.WingsYDossierID;
}

while(_uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Rows.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
{
    UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row =
                 (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow)_uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Rows.GetEnumerator().Current;
}
```

I don't know if it must be done with a foreach or a while? or what!!

Comment: I cant see any DossierID column in the details table

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do with each `DossierID` that you find and how it relates to the detail table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

1. Get all the `WingsDossierID` by doing a `Distinct()`
2. Iterate through this list of `WingsDossierID` -- *begin loop*

   1. Get the group of records for the current `WingsDossierID`
   2. Commit some operation with the group of records
3. *end loop*